# CSS padding keeps inheriting

Tags: css, overriding, padding, inheritance

I'm making a dropdown menu, but all the styles from the first ul is being added to the styles on every ul beneath the first ul.

I've tried overriding the styles using !important, and moving the css to different levels.
Anyone got a clue about whats going on here?

This image probaly explains it the best way: http://screencast.com/t/UrkRbjjaYctp

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The second UL has padding-left 40px and probably another 37px padding  because it is nested in the first ul. Whats wrong with this? :)

Comment: In other words - the padding is relative not absolute.

Comment: As a newcomer to SO, please remember to accept answers that you find useful and up vote other answers especially if people have shown effort and additional insight about analyzing your problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menuwrapper > ul{
padding-left:37px;
}
#menuwrapper ul ul {
padding-left:40px;
}
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! I was blinded about the whole nested thing, so I didn't think about this. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Paddings are added relatively.

If you don't want the nested `ul` to be padded `37px` you have to remove the padding from parent `ul` (or use some hack as negative margin e.g. *margin-left: -37px*).

If you remove padding from the parent you will probably need to add some margin to each its child to preserve the layout. I'd suggest to reconsider the HTML structure.