# Why doesn't this span inherit the padding of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
<span class="captionsection">Notes: <span class="grey">Lot behind chain-link fence was trimmed and well-maintained.</span></span>
```

And this css

```
.captionsection {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I thought that the inner span would inherit the padding of the outer span `.captionsection`? But this is not the case. [CSS padding keeps inheriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761331/css-padding-keeps-inheriting/15761657#15761657)

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: is there a `padding` rule already associated with the `grey` class in your CSS?

Comment: [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) is *not* an inherited CSS property. I think you're misunderstanding the content of the question you link to. The question's code has two `ul`s, one nested in the other, that both have a common padding rule applied to them, but the inner one has an additional overriding rule that is more specific. The common rule is not inherited -- it directly targets the inner `ul` *in addition to* the outer, but is overridden on the inner.

Comment: the "cascading" in "cascading style sheets" doesn't refer to inheriting from parent elements in html. Rather it refers to cascading rules in the css.

Answer (score 1):

Child elements do not inherit padding from parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work as expected because `<span>` is an inline element. Padding is not applied "in the middle" of its content, which includes the position the text wraps around.

If you wanted to keep the left padding for the whole height of the content in your example, you should have used a block element such as `<div>` for `.captionsection`.

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwDyb/)**

I should also mention that padding is not inherited (with the CSS meaning of the word "inherited") by child elements as you say -- but even if it were, you still would not have gotten the expected left padding after the wrap because of the above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, paddings are not inherited. But this is not the thing you mean, I believe, but that the second line is not indented.

A `<span>` is, by default, inline. This means it will be first layout as one line and then, if necessary, split to lines.

Here, the padding is only added to the first line because of this.

To make it work, you'll have to make the outer span a `block` or `inline-block` with the `display` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block;` Otherwise, span won't inherit the padding.

## CSS:

```
.captionsection {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

## Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JmV85/